# Implementing a TRUE/FALSE flag in an R function

Tags: r, function

I have an R function:

```
subsequences <- function(data){
  sequences.sts <- seqdef(data, left = "DEL", gaps = "DEL", right = "DEL")
  sub.sequences <- seqsubsn(sequences.sts, DSS = FALSE)
  (sub.sequences)
}
```

Now I want to implement a `TRUE/FALSE` flag to run some additional code for normalization, something like this:

```
subsequences <- function(data, normalization = TRUE/FALSE){
   sequences.sts <- seqdef(data, left = "DEL", gaps = "DEL", right = "DEL")
   sub.sequences <- seqsubsn(sequences.sts, DSS = FALSE)
   (sub.sequences)  

      IF normalization=TRUE, RUN CODE BELOW, IF FALSE -> END
         sequences.length <- seqlength(sequences.sts)
         order_normalized <- sub.sequences/(2^(max(sequences.length)))

   (order_normalized*1000000)
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Please read any introductory guide to R.  It will address proper `if` syntax as well as function definition and default arguments... FWIW, it would look like `if(normalization) {do stuff} else {return(whatever)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(TraMineR)

subsequences <- function(data, normalization){
  sequences.sts <- seqdef(data, left = "DEL", gaps = "DEL", right = "DEL")
  sub.sequences <- seqsubsn(sequences.sts, DSS = FALSE) 

  if(normalization){
  sequences.length <- seqlength(sequences.sts)
  order_normalized <- sub.sequences/(2^(max(sequences.length)))
  (order_normalized*1000000)}

  else {return(sub.sequences)}
}
```